# Hashmap element cannot be override even through hashCode() and equals()?

Tags: java

Here is my code in make sure to add student information with name ,age and their address. In order to make sure the student is unique. I use the `hashCode()` and `equals()` to make sure data integrity. The same name of student will be considered as override.

Problem is: The same information is never be cleaned out, Anybody know why? It seems the `hashCode()` and `equals()` never work.

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student>{

    private String name;
    private int age;

    Student(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int hashcode(){

        return name.hashCode() + age *34;
    }

    //override equals method
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(!(obj instanceof Student))
            throw new ClassCastException("The data type is not match!");

        Student s = (Student)obj;
        return this.name.equals(s.name) && this.age==s.age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        int num = new Integer(this.age).compareTo(new Integer(s.age));
        if (num == 0)
                return this.name.compareTo(s.name);
        return num;
    }
}

public class HashMapDemo1 {

    public static void main (String[] agrs){

        HashMap<Student,String> hs = new HashMap<Student,String>();

        hs.put(new Student("James",27),"Texas");
        hs.put(new Student("James",27), "California");
        hs.put(new Student("James",27), "New mexico");

        hs.put(new Student("Jack",22),"New York");
        hs.put(new Student("John",25),"Chicago");
        hs.put(new Student("Francis",26),"Florida");

        Set<Student> Keyset = hs.keySet();
        Iterator<Student> it = Keyset.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Student stu = it.next();
            String addr = hs.get(stu);
            System.out.print(stu.getName()+stu.getAge()+"..." +addr+"\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: What's the output of your program?

Comment: class Student implements Comparable<Student>, the generic is student. I missed it when I put it on the page.

Comment: By the way, `equals` should not throw a `ClassCastException` if `obj` is not an instance of `Student`, it should `return false`.

Comment: @Radiodef It is list of name, age,address without duplicate Student, which means, the James will be overrided  and have only the last address putted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hashcode != hashCode`

Be sure to use the `@Override` annotation whenever you think that you are overriding a super-class's method, as this will allow the compiler to notify you if/when you are wrong. As you're finding out, it's much easier to fix errors at the compilation stage rather than the run-time stage.

Myself, I'd not use the age field as part of equals or hashCode since age can change for a student with time. I'd use `Date birthDate` or some other invariant instead.

And also I agree with Radiodef: the `equals(...)` method  should not throw an exception. If the parameter object is not Student type, simply return false.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is a careless mistake.

Comment: Hello, btw, The reason why i did not return false is that I want to make the code can give more feedback if the exception happens. If I just return false, nothing else I can get from that. Is there better way to do this?

Comment: There shouldn't ever be a reason to compare the equality of a `Student` with an instance of another class, when you're writing type-safe code (i.e. not using collections with [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)).

Comment: @MickMnemonic: but that's not the contract that `Object#equals` is require or expected to follow. The only expectation is that it will check the current object vs. the parameter object and check for equality, nothing more or less. The parameter could be `null` and the method should work correctly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, the comment was addressed to the OP. My point was that there shouldn't be a reason for the feedback (via a `ClassCastException`) that the OP is suggesting. Even though the contract of `Object.equals` says nothing about (run-time) exceptions, `equals` is generally not expected to throw exceptions (think [Liskov substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thanks for the comment. I see the point you described.

Answer (score 1):

The method you have implemented is `public int hashcode()`.
It should be `public int hashCode()`.